# Configuration apache

Tags: apache2

I try to configure apache but unsuccessfully : when i type `http://localhost` i've got a 403 error.

apache2 is properly installed, i created the file myusername.conf in etc/apache2/users with the following content :

```
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The permissions of the file are : `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel`

and in the content of the http.conf file is (i spare you most of the comments, it's long enough) :

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_default_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_default_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache2/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module libexec/apache2/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
LoadModule ident_module libexec/apache2/mod_ident.so
LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
User _www
Group _www

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites"


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

<Files "rsrc">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
<DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</DirectoryMatch>


ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock /private/var/run/cgisock
</IfModule>


Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

TraceEnable off

 Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

NameVirtualHost *:80
 Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

If anyone has an idea, i'd be grateful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have `DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites"` but the `<Directory>` block is in `etc/apache2/users/myusername.conf`

I can't see any reference to `etc/apache2/users/myusername.conf` in your `http.conf`, so I'd start by checking whether that file is indeed getting loaded as a configuration file. The easiest way to do this (but most destructive, if it's a live server) is to introduce a syntax error in that file and reload the server.

Comment: indeed there nowhere a reference of 'etc/apache2/users/myusername.conf' (it's not a part i forgot to past). But i go through 3 or 4 tutorial and never seen anything mentioning it, how is it supposed to be mentioned ?

How do you suggest to introduce a syntax error ?

Comment: You can introduce a syntax error by writing nonsensical stuff, for example, removing a trailing or leading `>` from an existing tag

Comment: I've gone through a new proper install again and somehow it seems to work now, thanks again.